# What's the difference between @CacheEvict(...) and @CacheEvict(value , allEntries )?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-framework-beans

I noticed a few lines of @CacheEvict("Settings") in some source code and was curious if does the same thing as CacheEvict(value = "Settings" , allEntries = true )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `@CacheEvict` is specified without a `key` attribute, all method parameters are used to construct the key for the entry to be evicted, so

```
@CacheEvict("Settings")
public String doThing(String foo, Integer bar) {
    // ...
}
```

... will evict the entry with the composite key {`foo`, `bar`}. The default key generator used to construct the composite key is `SimpleKeyGenerator`, which returns `SimpleKey` instances that hold references to the method parameters for comparison.

If the method has no parameters, the default key is `SimpleKey.EMPTY`.

The attribute `allEntries` can't be set to `true` if you do specify a `key` attribute; they're mutually exclusive. If it is set to `true` all entries in the cache will be removed every time the annotated method is called.

So...

```
@CacheEvict("Settings", allEntries = true)
public String doThing(String foo, Integer bar) {
    // ...
}
```

... will empty the `Settings` cache every time the method is called, regardless of the method parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Just give a look at its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#allEntries--).
You'll notice the default value for `allEntries` is `false`. So no, it is **not** the same thing.
Use `allEntries = true` only when you want a fresh cache each time an operation is performed.

> Whether all the entries inside the cache(s) are removed. By default,
>   only the value under the associated key is removed.

If you want to see the implementation details, just look at [Coffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/tree/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache).